# Dynamically update form text field with array variable after choosing option in Dropdown box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a fantasy baseball league with several teams and each team has many players on their roster. So, I have a page that displays the roster.  Each player on the roster can be assigned a contract by selecting the term in a dropdown.  I then need to have the player's base_salary updated in the text field at the bottom of the page dynamically.  A team can select multiple players, so I need the box to increment the total salaries of the players selected.  I had this working with a checkbox when I only needed to track if the player was under contract or not and I could pass along the player salary within the value of the checkbox, but now there are multiple contract types, hence the dropdown.  So, my java fuunction still contains some of the old code for reference....  I can't figure how to pass along and "track" the incremental salary values as the dropdowns are selected.  The salaries are fetched from a db and placed in $base_salary.  Thanks in advance!!

Here is my code so far (revised)....

```
<form method='post' action='../keepers_updated' name='form1' id='form1'>
<select name='contracts[]' id='contracts' onchange='changeClass(this)'>
  <option value=>None</option>
  <option value=<php '$keeper'; ?> data-total=<php '$current_base_salary'; ?>Std.Keeper</option>
  <option value=<php '$contract_1'; ?> data-total=<php '$current_base_salary'; ?>>1</option>
  <option value=<php '$contract_3'; ?> data-total=<php '$current_base_salary'; ?>>3</option>
  <option value=<php '$contract_5'; ?> data-total=<php '$current_base_salary'; ?>>5</option>
  <option value=<php '$franchise'; ?> data-total=<php '$current_base_salary'; ?>>F Tag</option>
</select>
</td>
<td width='10px' align='center' ><php $current_teamID; ?></td>
<td width='60px' align='center' ><php $current_positionID; ?></td>
<td width='10px' align='center' width='10px' ><php $$current_base_salary; ?></td>
<td><input type='text' name='textfield' id='textfield' value=<php $$total_salary; ?> readonly />
<b>Total Keeper Salary</b></td>

<input type='hidden' name='TeamsID' value=<php $Teams_ID; ?>>
<input type='submit' value='Save keepers'>
</form>
</table>
```

I took a stab at the java.  I found a post somewhere that mentioned a "data" attribute in the option value tag.  Not sure if it can apply here, but I tried it...

```
function changeClass() {
  function recalculate() {
var elem=document.getElementById("textfield"); 
    var sum = 0;

    $('#contracts').find('option:selected').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).data("total"));
    });

    elem.value='$'+sum;
  }

  $('#contracts').change(ChangeClass() {
    recalculate();
  });

});
</script>
```

The form loads with all the contract options, but the text field does not update with anything.  Maintains the default value no matter what I choose in the dropdowns.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**  Ok....  I figured out that i can pass two variables in the select option value field.  I seperated the contract type and base_salary with a : like so, (value=$contract_1:$base_salary).  I am able to use this code to split the values and it works...

```
function changeClass(value) {
  var textfield;
  var select = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
  var value_parts = value.split(':');
  var count = select.length;
  document.getElementById('textfield').value = value_parts[1];
  return;
}
```

Now the trouble I have is getting the total number of selections made so I can create a for loop to accumulate the salaries.

Comment: It's either that  or call pho on and off on each line...  This way is cleaner to me.  :).

Comment: I'd start by changing "onchamge" to "onchange", deciding whether the id should be "contracts" or "contract" and terminating the echo line with the textfield. Also, why not separate all that html and javascript from the php by putting the php in "<?php" blocks?

Comment: Thanks Flynn...  Not sure how I missed that typo in onchange.  How do I get the player's base_salary variable into javascript based on which player is selected to be under contract and accumulate the total salaries based on multiple selections?  It doesn't matter which contract they choose, the salary is the same.

Comment: Since this is a JavaScript question, your PHP is not relevant. Why not just show the resulting HTML?

Comment: based on earlier comments I separated out the html and java and put the php in it's "proper" blocks.  Still need help with getting and accumulating player salaries dynamically into text field based on if a player is selected in a dropdown.  Thx!

Comment: @JimW Java != JavaScript